# ICMP firewall policy for standard ubuntu desktop

Tags: ubuntu, networking, firewall, iptables, icmp

For a standard desktop computer running `Ubuntu 12.04` behind a NAT router, what `ICMP` packets should one accept in the firewall, say `iptables`?

It seems there is often conflicting advice; some say block `ICMP` completely, others say one needs `ICMP` particularly for things thing establishing the `MTU` (avoiding `MTU black holes` etc). What is a good `ICMP` policy for a computer as described above?

Would it be sufficient to allow outgoing `ICMP` and incoming `RELATED/ESTABLISHED`, or should one really be opening an incoming port for certain types of `NEW` `ICMP` packets too?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there should not be problems if you will block incoming ICMP for your desktop computer.

And if your computer is behind the NAT router and uses internal IP - external ICMP traffic would not reach it anyway.

But if you will block it completely than you will be unable to ping external networks. If you want to be able to do so, you have to specify PERMIT rule for incoming ICMP echo-reply packets.

Comment: Some ICMP seems to be getting through the router to `iptables` though: `netfilter:in dropped: IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=********* SRC=80.101.144.29 DST=192.168.1.79 LEN=88 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=40460 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=3 [SRC=192.168.1.79 DST=80.101.144.29 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=6658 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50060 DPT=32435 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 ]`. This was a destination unreachable response back to me, after my computer tried SYN another on via peer2peer.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if it's true that RELATED/ESTABLISHED can't be used with ICMP, see here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-9-allow-icmp-ping.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I removed this line from my answer. On the matter of the question - If I would be on your place I would just block ICMP and see how it goes for couple of days. If everything will be fine - do not bother yourself and leave it like that. If problems will arise - than investigate. Premature optimization is the root of all evil (:

Comment: Well, actually I'm a little confused, as my default INPUT and OUTPUT iptables policies are DROP, yet if I `ping google.com` then my packets get out and the replies return. Despite the fact I've not actually set a rule to allow ICMP (either outbound or inbound) so I don't understand how the packets are escaping and not being dropped and logged like everything else.

Comment: I do have the default "kernel tunings" at the top of my iptables script: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts,
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_source_route,
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies,
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects,
echo 0 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/send_redirects,
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter,
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/log_martians`, not sure if that is responsible...

Comment: I see. If you able to ping there should be something that allows it. I would try disabling rules / changing settings one by one and check if ping still goes. At some point you will find one rule or setting which allows it. Hope it will help you to get out of confusion.

Comment: turned out this was because I had allowed `root` unlimited outbound and `ping` is owned by root, so even when run by non-root user its packets got through (despite no explict ICMP allow rules).

Comment: I have had the firewall like this for some time and the lack of ICMP has made no notifiable difference to my system. I am, however, still worried that without being able to receive icmp, the system may not be able to optimally set the MTU etc etc. I really don't know if this is an issue for my setup (desktop behind NAT router) though. Oh well, for now I will leave it.

Comment: I just Googled that. Found one [article](http://www.znep.com/~marcs/mtu/) about that. Go to the section "Now, to the problem with ICMP filtering and PMTU-D..."

Comment: thanks, great link. It seems `iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 3/4 -j ACCEPT` is probably needed to allow me to hear the router asking me to reduce my packet size.  Another good link is: http://eugene.oregontechsupport.com/articles/icmp.txt